# pd.DataFrame.ewm().cov() just get the last cov

Tags: python, pandas

mat is a pd.DataFrame of daily ret of several stocks.
the function of pd.DataFrame.ewm().cov() compute each day covariance of these stocks. when the shape of mat is 250 * 2972, it cost too much time and return 250 matrix of covariance. But i just want to get the last one of these cov. How could i do more easily and save some time ?

```
  mat.head()
  SecuCode  000001  000002  000004  000005  
  TradingDay                                                                                    

  2016-08-31    0.00211 0.09547 0.0 0.00802 
  2016-09-01    -0.00422    -0.06163    0.0 -0.01746    
  2016-09-02    0.00000 0.01398 0.0 -0.00680
  2016-09-05    -0.00318    -0.01398    0.0 0.00408 
  2016-09-06    -0.00106    -0.00513    0.0 0.01081 
  5 rows × 2972 columns
```